# New class extends FrameLayout could not be instantiated

Tags: android, android-layout

I wrote a class extends FrameLayout.

```
public class ReaderFrameLayout extends FrameLayout
{
    public ReaderFrameLayout(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ReaderFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ReaderFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
        WebView readerWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_reader_webview);
        readerWebView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                Log.d("ReaderFrameLayout", "setOnTouchListener");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And add it to a fragment.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.mbs.helpers.ReaderFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_reader_webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </com.mbs.helpers.ReaderFrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

An error in Eclipse:

**com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.mbs.helpers.ReaderFrameLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse**

The application does not work, of course.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the eclipse error you are referring to is related to graphical layout. This is in no way related to operation on the device. So do explain what does not work ? does it throw error? All I see is two layouts and nothing else, if you set above layout, it will be empty

Answer (score 0):

Just create the web view programmatically :

```
public ReaderFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
    WebView readerWebView = new WebView(context);
    addView(readerWebView);
    readerWebView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            Log.d("ReaderFrameLayout", "setOnTouchListener");
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

and remove it from the XML layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.mbs.helpers.ReaderFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you really want to create your custom view from an XML layout, then you need to do that in a separate XML file and inflate it in your custom class.

For instace, `res/layout/reader.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_reader_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And in your code:

```
    public ReaderFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defaultStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.reader, this);
        WebView readerWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_reader_webview);
        readerWebView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("ReaderFrameLayout", "setOnTouchListener");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```